# php explode not work unreasonable

Tags: php, function, path, root, explode

this is the 'connect.php' code:

```
<?php
  if(!require_once(explode('root',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])[0].'root/core/function.php')) die('file not found');
```

the code was works perfectly before I transferring to new server

and now whatever I try how many time still display error:

```
[09-Jan-2013 17:05:39] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/wwwroot/root/core/connect.php on line 2
[09-Jan-2013 17:10:10] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/wwwroot/root/core/connect.php on line 2
```

and I tried to open a new php file to test it:

```
<?php
print_r(explode('root',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']));
?>
```

and result should work!!

```
Array (
       [0] => /home/public_html/
       [1] => /core/
      )
```

what the hell!?

Comment: just to make sure. can you try $myServer = explode('root',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);---$myDoc = $myServer[0]; ---- and then ------  if(!require_once($myDoc.'root/core/function.php')) die('file not found');

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your PHP version on server do not support constructs like `explode('root',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])[0]`. This was added only in PHP 5.4

You can assign your explode result to a variable and then access it like a regular array.

Comment: Thanks man. I couldn't imagine why my code crashes at `explode` while it works fine on my home machine...

Answer (score 2):

What is the new PHP version?

You could try something like this:

```
$pathToCheck = explode("root",$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);
if(count($pathToCheck) <= 1 || !require_once($pathToCheck[0]."root/core/function.php"))
    die("file not found");
```

Answer (score 1):

it is supported by 4+ php versions like 4.1
more information
http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_explode.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$path = explode ('root', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
require_once $path[0];
```